# Setup separate app volume controls

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can i control my app's output volume.

I've got an app that uses https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer to stream mp3 files from the internet. The `AudioStreamer` class does not have a way to change output volume and I don't want to change system volume.

Many apps do this:

- iTunes
- Spotify
- MPlayerX
- Most Audio Players

Edit: If you're hear about AudioStreamer, I've since switched to Apple's AVPlayer, which i've found far simpler and superior.  Easy volume adjustment too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AudioStreamer` and I'm guessing most OSX media players use the AudioToolbox framework.  AudioToolbox uses a programming interface called `AudioQueue` to playback media files.  Here is the way to adjust the volume using `AudioQueue`.

```
AudioQueueSetParameter(audioQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 0.5);
```

- `audioQueue` is an AudioQueRef
- `kAudioQueueParam_Volume` tells `AudioQueueSetParameter()` to change the Volume Parameter
- `0.5` is the volume from 0.0 - 1.0

More details on AudioQueue: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVAudioPlayer`, it has an instance method `setVolume:` to set the output volume:

```
AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer = ...
float volume = aVolumeValue / 100.f; // aVolumeValue can be 0~100
[audioPlayer setVolume:volume];
[audioPlayer play];
```

By the way, you can store the `aVolumeValue` into `NSUserDefaults`, and control it by `UISlider` object.

Comment: I'm on OSX and AudioStreamer handles playing.  Would AVAudioPlayer still work to adjust app volume?